# Guidance needed with using LIKE operator in If-Else block of a Snowflake Stored procedure

Tags: if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like, procedure

I'm trying to create a Snowflake stored procedure, similar to the below code. But the like operator in the if-else block is not working.

Stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure test_stored_procedure(inputvalue varchar)
returns string not null
language javascript
as 
$$
    if (inputvalue like '%abc%') { return 'valid input' } else { return 'invalid input'}
$$
 ;
```

I am getting the below error while calling the procedure

> JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in test_stored_procedure at ' if (inputvalue like '%abc%') { return 'valid input' } else { return 'invalid input'}' position 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript equivalent of `LIKE '%abc%'` is `includes('abc')`:

```
create or replace procedure test_stored_procedure(inputvalue VARCHAR)
returns string not null
language javascript
as 
$$
if ( INPUTVALUE.includes('abc')) {
  return 'valid input';
} 
else { 
  return 'invalid input';
}
$$;
```

Test:

```
CALL TEST_STORED_PROCEDURE('fabc');
-- valid input

CALL TEST_STORED_PROCEDURE('xyz');
-- invalid input
```

Notes:

Statements should be terminated with `;` and 
[Case-sensitivity in JavaScript Arguments](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#case-sensitivity-in-javascript-arguments):

> **For stored procedures (and UDFs) that use JavaScript, identifiers (such as argument names) in the SQL portion of the statement are converted to uppercase automatically** (unless you delimit the identifier with double quotes), while argument names in the JavaScript portion will be left in their original case